# Keep minimum value of field A and corresponding value of field B in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions, min

Say I have the following table:

```
Category rank score
a        3    100
a        1    105
a        2    110
b        2    102
b        7    107
b        3    95
```

I would like to know both the most efficient and the most visually elegant way of getting the lines having the minimum rank for each category.

In my example the result would be

```
Category rank score
a        1    105
b        2    102
```

The solutions I came up with seem inefficient and ugly for something that seems quite straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical solution is to use `row_number()`:

```
select category, rank, score
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category order by rank) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Whether or not you think this is elegant is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Below solution uses the concept of CTE....

```
with cte as 
(
select category, rank, score, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY category ORDER BY rank ) AS row_num
from t
)
select category, rank, score from cte
where row_num=1
```